# Hexadecimal/Binary to QR Code

Tags: arrays, binary, hex, zxing, qr-code

Is there any way to create a QR code from a byte array? I decoded one using "zxing", and now that I changed it, I want to turn it back. If there is a solution, please tell me. Here is the code churned from "zxing":

```
40 07 01 18 2b 3c ba 4c   0e 1d bd 8a b4 23 29 10
40 72 b0 fe 7f 12 7c 71   2f f2 2b 8e 2a 2b b9 88
21 93 94 83 c8 b2 57 d8   a1 5f 0f 70 c3 56 8f 88
81 16 70 1d b0 b8 dc 0d   ce 4c 1e 7c 01 85 26 74
d3 ae ce 6b b0 4b 02 6a   45 50 11 1b 65 2c 5e e2
cc 4a 65 f2 04 94 27 84   6a 88 2c c1 92 8b 65 b3
4d a4 9a 07 4f 41 14 bd   6e b6 ab 02 ca cc 7b dd
fe 34 60 ec 11 ec 11 ec   11 ec
```

The array format and the spaces seem important. Now, here is the original QR Code I put into "zxing":

[image]

Thanks everyone!

---In Response to the On-Hold Message:---
I tried to convert the array to a QR Code, but it was much different from the original. I expected it to be the same.

Comment: if you can use zxing to read a QR code, surely you can work out how to print one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways of encoding the same information for a QR code. One of several possible mask patterns is applied to the information in order to produce a QR code that has a well distributed pattern of black and white pixels. In a QR code on a piece of paper that is bent in some way, the apparent distances of the pixels may vary. Long series of white or black pixels could disturb the reading process. When reading a QR code, the edges between the white and black pixels are used to synchronize with the raster used.

In order to test if the printed QR code is correct, re-read it and compare the information with the information of the original QR code. Don't compare the pictures!

See [QR code / Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#Encoding) on Wikipedia.